# Missing artifact error in Maven build/pom.xml

Tags: java, maven, pom.xml

Using Maven build I am getting this error. (both in Maven build and pom.xml file)
Missing artifact org.bytedeco.javacpp-presets:artoolkitplus:jar:2.3.1-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT and so on for every dependency.

I tried deleting the org.bytedeco folder from my local .m2 repository, but the error persists.

My pom.xml file is as follows

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.ayman</groupId>
  <artifactId>JavaCV</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>


  <name>JavaCV</name>
  <description>Java interface to OpenCV and more</description>
  <url>http://bytedeco.org/javacv/</url>

  <licenses>
    <license>
      <name>Apache License, Version 2.0</name>
      <url>http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0</url>
      <distribution>repo</distribution>
    </license>
    <license>
      <name>GNU General Public License (GPL) version 2, or any later version</name>
      <url>http://www.gnu.org/licenses/</url>
      <distribution>repo</distribution>
    </license>
    <license>
      <name>GPLv2 with Classpath exception</name>
      <url>http://www.gnu.org/software/classpath/license.html</url>
      <distribution>repo</distribution>
    </license>
  </licenses>

  <developers>
    <developer>
      <name>Ayman</name>
      <email>ayman.patel@gmail.com</email>
    </developer>
  </developers>

  <prerequisites>
    <maven>3.0</maven>
  </prerequisites>

  <scm>
    <url>https://github.com/bytedeco/javacv</url>
    <connection>scm:git:git://github.com/bytedeco/javacv.git</connection>
    <developerConnection>scm:git:ssh://git@github.com/bytedeco/javacv.git</developerConnection>
  </scm>

  <distributionManagement>
    <snapshotRepository>
      <id>sonatype-nexus-snapshots</id>
      <name>Sonatype Nexus Snapshots</name>
      <url>https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/</url>
    </snapshotRepository>
    <repository>
      <id>sonatype-nexus-staging</id>
      <name>Sonatype Nexus Staging</name>
      <url>https://oss.sonatype.org/service/local/staging/deploy/maven2/</url>
    </repository>
  </distributionManagement>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <maven.build.timestamp.format>yyyyMMddhhmm</maven.build.timestamp.format>
    <javacpp.version>${project.version}</javacpp.version>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.bytedeco</groupId>
      <artifactId>javacpp</artifactId>
      <version>${javacpp.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.bytedeco.javacpp-presets</groupId>
      <artifactId>opencv</artifactId>
      <version>3.4.1-${javacpp.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.bytedeco.javacpp-presets</groupId>
      <artifactId>ffmpeg</artifactId>
      <version>4.0-${javacpp.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.bytedeco.javacpp-presets</groupId>
      <artifactId>flycapture</artifactId>
      <version>2.11.3.121-${javacpp.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.bytedeco.javacpp-presets</groupId>
      <artifactId>libdc1394</artifactId>
      <version>2.2.5-${javacpp.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.bytedeco.javacpp-presets</groupId>
      <artifactId>libfreenect</artifactId>
      <version>0.5.3-${javacpp.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.bytedeco.javacpp-presets</groupId>
      <artifactId>libfreenect2</artifactId>
      <version>0.2.0-${javacpp.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.bytedeco.javacpp-presets</groupId>
      <artifactId>librealsense</artifactId>
      <version>1.12.1-${javacpp.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.bytedeco.javacpp-presets</groupId>
      <artifactId>videoinput</artifactId>
      <version>0.200-${javacpp.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.bytedeco.javacpp-presets</groupId>
      <artifactId>artoolkitplus</artifactId>
      <version>2.3.1-${javacpp.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.bytedeco.javacpp-presets</groupId>
      <artifactId>flandmark</artifactId>
      <version>1.07-${javacpp.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.bytedeco.javacpp-presets</groupId>
      <artifactId>leptonica</artifactId>
      <version>1.76.0-${javacpp.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.bytedeco.javacpp-presets</groupId>
      <artifactId>tesseract</artifactId>
      <version>4.0.0-beta.1-${javacpp.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.google.android</groupId>
      <artifactId>android</artifactId>
      <version>4.1.1.4</version>
      <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>*</groupId>
            <artifactId>*</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
      </exclusions>
      <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.jogamp.gluegen</groupId>
      <artifactId>gluegen-rt-main</artifactId>
      <version>2.3.1</version>
      <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.jogamp.jogl</groupId>
      <artifactId>jogl-all-main</artifactId>
      <version>2.3.1</version>
      <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.jogamp.jocl</groupId>
      <artifactId>jocl-main</artifactId>
      <version>2.3.1</version>
      <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>

  <repositories>
    <repository>
      <id>sonatype-nexus-snapshots</id>
      <name>Sonatype Nexus Snapshots</name>
      <url>https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots</url>
      <releases>
        <enabled>false</enabled>
      </releases>
      <snapshots>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
      </snapshots>
    </repository>
  </repositories>

  <build>
    <finalName>${project.artifactId}</finalName>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.3</version>
        <configuration>
          <source>1.7</source>
          <target>1.7</target>
          <excludes>
            <exclude>org/bytedeco/javacv/FlyCaptureFrameGrabber.java</exclude>
          </excludes>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.2</version>
        <configuration>
          <archive>
            <manifest>
              <mainClass>org.bytedeco.javacv.JavaCV</mainClass>
              <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
            </manifest>
            <manifestEntries>
              <!-- <addClasspath/> is broken: http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/MJAR-61 -->
              <Class-Path>. javacpp.jar opencv.jar ffmpeg.jar flycapture.jar libdc1394.jar libfreenect.jar libfreenect2.jar librealsense.jar videoinput.jar artoolkitplus.jar flandmark.jar</Class-Path>
              <Name>org/bytedeco/javacv/</Name>
              <Implementation-Title>${project.name}</Implementation-Title>
              <Implementation-Vendor>Bytedeco</Implementation-Vendor>
              <Implementation-Version>${project.version}</Implementation-Version>
              <Specification-Title>${project.name}</Specification-Title>
              <Specification-Vendor>Bytedeco</Specification-Vendor>
              <Specification-Version>${project.version}</Specification-Version>
            </manifestEntries>
          </archive>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-install-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.2</version>
        <configuration>
          <createChecksum>true</createChecksum>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-source-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.1</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>attach-source</id>
            <goals>
              <goal>jar-no-fork</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.10.4</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>attach-javadocs</id>
            <goals>
              <goal>jar</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <links>
                <link>http://bytedeco.org/javacpp/apidocs/</link>
                <link>http://bytedeco.org/javacpp-presets/opencv/apidocs/</link>
                <link>http://bytedeco.org/javacpp-presets/ffmpeg/apidocs/</link>
                <link>http://bytedeco.org/javacpp-presets/flycapture/apidocs/</link>
                <link>http://bytedeco.org/javacpp-presets/libdc1394/apidocs/</link>
                <link>http://bytedeco.org/javacpp-presets/libfreenect/apidocs/</link>
                <link>http://bytedeco.org/javacpp-presets/libfreenect2/apidocs/</link>
                <link>http://bytedeco.org/javacpp-presets/librealsense/apidocs/</link>
                <link>http://bytedeco.org/javacpp-presets/videoinput/apidocs/</link>
                <link>http://bytedeco.org/javacpp-presets/artoolkitplus/apidocs/</link>
                <link>http://bytedeco.org/javacpp-presets/flandmark/apidocs/</link>
                <link>https://developer.android.com/reference/</link>
                <link>https://jogamp.org/deployment/v2.3.1/javadoc/gluegen/javadoc/</link>
                <link>https://jogamp.org/deployment/v2.3.1/javadoc/jocl/javadoc/</link>
                <link>https://jogamp.org/deployment/v2.3.1/javadoc/jogl/javadoc/</link>
                <link>http://junit.org/junit4/javadoc/4.11/</link>
              </links>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.8.2</version>
        <configuration>
          <skip>true</skip>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.sonatype.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>nexus-staging-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.6</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>default-deploy</id>
            <phase>deploy</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>deploy</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
        <extensions>true</extensions>
        <configuration>
          <serverId>sonatype-nexus-staging</serverId>
          <nexusUrl>https://oss.sonatype.org/</nexusUrl>
          <skipStagingRepositoryClose>true</skipStagingRepositoryClose>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>

  <profiles>
    <profile>
      <id>doclint-java8-disable</id>
      <activation>
        <jdk>[1.8,)</jdk>
      </activation>
      <build>
        <plugins>
          <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
              <additionalparam>-Xdoclint:none</additionalparam>
            </configuration>
          </plugin>
        </plugins>
      </build>
    </profile>

    <profile>
      <id>sign-artifacts</id>
      <activation>
        <property>
          <name>performRelease</name>
          <value>true</value>
        </property>
      </activation>
      <build>
        <plugins>
          <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-gpg-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.6</version>
            <executions>
              <execution>
                <id>sign-artifacts</id>
                <phase>verify</phase>
                <goals>
                  <goal>sign</goal>
                </goals>
              </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
              <passphrase>${env.GPG_PASSPHRASE}</passphrase>
              <useAgent>false</useAgent>
            </configuration>
          </plugin>
        </plugins>
      </build>
    </profile>
  </profiles>

</project>

</project>
```

Comment: In [maven central repository](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.bytedeco.javacpp-presets/artoolkitplus) is no snapshot available . why you use the Project-Version as the dependency Version?

Comment: I'm following this link, that's why https://github.com/bytedeco/javacv/blob/master/pom.xml

Comment: but this is the pom of the original developer. Use a fix Version for your project

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do not use the project.version as version for the dependency. Always use a fix version

Change

```
<javacpp.version>${project.version}</javacpp.version>
```

to

```
<javacpp.version>2.3.1-1.4.1</javacpp.version>
```

Comment: I am sorry but I am a novice in this area, but the error is still present.

Comment: It can not be the same error. Can you Show edited pom and the message

Comment: This might sound out of hand...but I have another project  [ https://github.com/deeplearning4j/dl4j-examples ]  which downloaded javacpp presents dependencies (even though it is not explicitly stated in its pom.xml), which implies that I have the files already...I assume I need to change my current project(not dl4j) pom.xml to compensate the already downloaded dependencies. It sounds an impossible task given my current setup :(